# THREE.js MIME Javascript module

Tags: javascript, html, module, three.js

I am getting this error when trying to load my three.js page live.
In my html I have specified module as my type:

```
<script type="module" src="./sketch.js"></script>
```

**ERROR:**

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

This is my folder structure. I have the three.js package folder called "three.js-master"
[image]

Thank you for your help.

**I am also getting this error now:**

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: What server are you using, and how is it configured? The error says your server is sending JavaScript (*.js) files as `text/html`, rather than `application/javascript`.

Comment: I am using npm.

Comment: I might have resolved the issue somewhat, but now getting this new issue. not sure if they are related.

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: Do some searching for "import maps." They aren't widely supported yet, but if you're just testing some things (in Chrome) with the intent of eventually migrating to a proper build tool, it should get your past the unresolved reference issue.